# How to add splash screens PWA to iPhone Next js

Tags: next.js, next-pwa

A project in Next js using `next-pwa`, I'm trying to add a splash screen for iPhone, but it doesn't work, has anyone had a similar problem
here code `_document.js`

PWA setup from this examples https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/tree/master/examples/web-push

here I use different extensions and pics for them and different meta tags from docs

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="PWA App" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 430px) and (device-height: 932px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_15_Pro_Max__iPhone_15_Plus__iPhone_14_Pro_Max_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 393px) and (device-height: 852px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_15_Pro__iPhone_15__iPhone_14_Pro_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 428px) and (device-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_14_Plus__iPhone_13_Pro_Max__iPhone_12_Pro_Max_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 390px) and (device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_14__iPhone_13_Pro__iPhone_13__iPhone_12_Pro__iPhone_12_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_13_mini__iPhone_12_mini__iPhone_11_Pro__iPhone_XS__iPhone_X_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_11_Pro_Max__iPhone_XS_Max_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_11__iPhone_XR_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_8_Plus__iPhone_7_Plus__iPhone_6s_Plus__iPhone_6_Plus_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_8__iPhone_7__iPhone_6s__iPhone_6__4.7__iPhone_SE_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/4__iPhone_SE__iPod_touch_5th_generation_and_later_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/12.9__iPad_Pro_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/11__iPad_Pro__10.5__iPad_Pro_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 820px) and (device-height: 1180px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/10.9__iPad_Air_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/10.5__iPad_Air_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 810px) and (device-height: 1080px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/10.2__iPad_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/9.7__iPad_Pro__7.9__iPad_mini__9.7__iPad_Air__9.7__iPad_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 744px) and (device-height: 1133px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
          href="splash_screens/8.3__iPad_Mini_landscape.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 430px) and (device-height: 932px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_15_Pro_Max__iPhone_15_Plus__iPhone_14_Pro_Max_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 393px) and (device-height: 852px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_15_Pro__iPhone_15__iPhone_14_Pro_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 428px) and (device-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_14_Plus__iPhone_13_Pro_Max__iPhone_12_Pro_Max_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 390px) and (device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_14__iPhone_13_Pro__iPhone_13__iPhone_12_Pro__iPhone_12_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_13_mini__iPhone_12_mini__iPhone_11_Pro__iPhone_XS__iPhone_X_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_11_Pro_Max__iPhone_XS_Max_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_11__iPhone_XR_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_8_Plus__iPhone_7_Plus__iPhone_6s_Plus__iPhone_6_Plus_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/iPhone_8__iPhone_7__iPhone_6s__iPhone_6__4.7__iPhone_SE_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/4__iPhone_SE__iPod_touch_5th_generation_and_later_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/12.9__iPad_Pro_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/11__iPad_Pro__10.5__iPad_Pro_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 820px) and (device-height: 1180px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/10.9__iPad_Air_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/10.5__iPad_Air_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 810px) and (device-height: 1080px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/10.2__iPad_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/9.7__iPad_Pro__7.9__iPad_mini__9.7__iPad_Air__9.7__iPad_portrait.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
          media="screen and (device-width: 744px) and (device-height: 1133px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)"
          href="splash_screens/8.3__iPad_Mini_portrait.png"
        />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `public/splash_screens` folder with all the splash images in it?

Comment: @Abraham yes. t